# ASP.NET MVC: How to merge/add new item into RouteValueDictionary

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, anonymous-types

I'm going to simplify my route declaration around of my asp.net mvc project. So I have created several method to do this.

```
context.MapExtendedRoute("Home".MergeWithAreaName(context),
                                 "www".MergeWithAppDomain(),
                                 "123".MergeWithDefaultRouteKeys(),
                                 new {Controller = "Home", Action = "Index"}.MergeWithDefaultRouteValues(),
                                 new {}.MergeWithDefaultRouteConstraints());
```

There isn't any problem with first three methods. But method 4 and 5 returns invalid value. The initial signature of (for example MergeWithDefaultRouteValues) is something like this:

```
public static object MergeWithDefaultRouteValues(this object defaultValues) {
        return new RouteValueDictionary(defaultValues) {{"Culture", "SomeValue"}};
    }
```

Which returns output like this(from RouteDebugger):

```
Count = 3, Keys = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+KeyCollection[System.String,System.Object], Values = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+ValueCollection[System.String,System.Object]
```

You can see none of Keys/Values is correct! Can anybody tell me how i can figure it out?

Signature of MapExtendedRoute:

```
MapExtendedRoute(this AreaRegistrationContext context, string name, string domain, string url, object defaults, object constraints)
```

Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this issue by adding new overload to MapExtendedRoute method and change signature to this:

```
MapExtendedRoute(this AreaRegistrationContext context, string name, string domain, string url, RouteValueDictionary defaults, RouteValueDictionary constraints)
```

The problem is from casting RouteValueDictionary to object, then casting back object to RouteValueDictionary! So Route Keys/Values come from first RouteValueDictionary Properties/Values.

```
var defaultValues = new {};

//this works fine
var x = new RouteValueDictionary(defaultValues) {{"Culture", null}};

//But when x casted to object
var obj = (object)x;

//And obj casted back to RouteValueDictionary
var x2 = new RouteValueDictionary(obj);

//Everything goes to be fail!
```